# How to plot a vertical area plot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Is there a straight forward way to plot an area plot using pandas, but orient the plot vertically?

for example to plot an area plot horizontally I can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.plot(kind='area');
```

[image]

I can plot a bar plot vertically with `'barh'`

```
df.plot(kind='barh');
```

[image]

But I can't figure out a straightforward way to get a area plot vertical

Comment: Hackiest option ever, but find a way to have matplotlib rotate your graph by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason pandas does not provide a vertical stack plot is that matplotlib [`stackplot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stackplot.html) is only for horizontal stacks.

However, a stackplot is nothing but a filled lineplot in the end. So you would get the desired plot by plotting the data with [`fill_betweenx()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_betweenx.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.rand(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.cumsum(df.values, axis=1)
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    ax.fill_betweenx(df.index, data[:,i], label=col, zorder=-i)
ax.margins(y=0)
ax.set_xlim(0, None)
ax.set_axisbelow(False)

ax.legend()


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(There should be a better solution)

Plot - Rotate 90 - Reflect Vertical

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot, transforms

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
base = plt.gca().transData
rot = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(90)
reflect_vertical = transforms.Affine2D(np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]))
df.plot(kind='area', transform= reflect_vertical + rot + base, ax=plt.gca(), xlim=(0, 3))
plt.gca().set_aspect(0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is along the lines of what I was thinking, I'm surprised this is necessary though